# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod Umlauts issues with UTF-8 and Windows-1252

Tags: powershell, rest, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

Upon executing Confluence REST API calls I get back a response encoded in UTF-8. However, when I export the results with either `Out-File` or `Export-CSV` even with the `-Encoding utf8` parameter German Umlauts are not correctly represented. For example, 'ü' is still 'Ã¼'.

From what I could gather it's due to the fact that PowerShell 5.1 natively relies on Windows-1252. I verified that Umlauts are preserved when using PowerShell Core by executing
 `[psobject].Assembly.GetTypes() | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'ClrFacade'} |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.GetMethod('GetDefaultEncoding', [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'nonpublic,static').Invoke($null, @())
  }`

Even changing the script file itself to use the encoding UTF-8 with BOM or Windows-1252 does not preserve Umlauts, neither in the PowerShell nor exportet output.

Do you know of any way to tell PowerShell 5.1 to preserve Umlauts while executing the REST call?

I cannot use PowerShell core as further operations require cmdlets which do net yet exist for PowerShell Core.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with the `-Outfile` parameter?

Comment: Do you know which part of your workflow is breaking the encoding? e.g. is it definitely invoke-restmethod, or maybe out-file or the viewer you're checking the file contents in? for example if i do this ```"ü" | out-file c:\temp\umlaut-utf8.txt -encoding utf8``` i get a file with the bytes "EF BB BF C3 BC 0D 0A" which shows "ü" in notepad, but "ï»¿Ã¼" in a hex editor.

Comment: @AdminOfThings, what you suggested does indeed preserve the Umlauts, that's nice. However, I noticed that it only does so when specifying the .txt extension. .csv does not work here as well. Ultimately, I would want to store REST response details in a CSV-file.

Comment: @mclayton, I suspect it's the shell, i.e. PowerShell 5.1. in VSCode (but also powershell.exe in standalone mode behaves the same). I guess `"ü" | out-file` works because it's not first "internalized" by the shell as when executing a cmdlet. So to generalize, each Umlaut that is processed by a cmdlet in PS 5.1. should exhibit the encoding issue.

Comment: do you have a simple repro i can try here? i tried this in a powershell.exe console, but the file shows the umlaut fine in notepad: ```$xmldoc = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9C";
$xmldoc.DocumentElement.InnerText | out-file c:\temp\out.txt -Encoding utf8;```

Comment: @mclayton, yes, that works just fine for some reason. I dug a little deeper, it might be a Confluence pecularity. The response does not return a charset in the Content-Type; see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-56064

I also just verified with Fiddler that executing the pure REST call does indeed not return a charset, too bad.

Comment: In that case, you can possibly pull the raw bytes from the response and decode them yourself using the appropriate content type. I can post an example in a bit, but just search for “decode bytes utf8 .net” or similar and you might find an answer...

Comment: I believe I have found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265157/how-do-i-change-my-powershell-script-so-that-it-writes-out-file-in-ansi-window. I don't quite understand it yet but simply adding the `-Encoding default` parameter fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it looks like the Confluence API encodes http responses using UTF8, but does *not* include the "Content-Type" header to indicate that.

The HTTP specification for the [charset parameter](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index#charset) says that in the absence of this header, the client should assume it's encoded with ISO-8859-1 character set, so what is happening in your request is something like this:

```bsh
# server (Confluence API) encodes response text using utf8
PS> $text = "ü";
PS> $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($text);
PS> write-host $bytes;
195 188

# client (Invoke-RestMethod) decodes bytes as ISO-8859-1
PS> $text = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString($bytes);
PS> write-host $text;
Ã¼
```

Given that you can't control what the server sends, you'll either need to capture the raw bytes yourself (e.g. using [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)) and decode them using UTF8, or modify the existing response to compensate for the encoding mismatch (e.g. below).

```
PS> $text = "Ã¼"
PS> $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($text)
PS> $text = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes)
PS> write-host $text
ü
```

Note that if you use the `-Outfile` parameter of Invoke-RestMethod it presumably streams the response bytes directly to disk without decoding or encoding them, so the resultant file already contains `utf8 $bytes` rather than `utf8 $bytes -> string decoded using ISO-8859-1 -> file bytes encoded using utf8`