# Polish characters from Invoke-RestMethod or Invoke-webrequest not displaying correctly in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, diacritics, polish

I have a problem with getting data with Polish diacritics from an Invoke webrequest or Invoke-Restmethod.
WHen I retrieve the data I am getting strange characters instead of the correct Polish diacritics.
for example:
Plec              : MÄÅ¼czyzna

When I try the same web request in postman I get the correct diacritics:
"Plec": "Mężczyzna",

when I copy the PowerShell script that is created via Postman I do not get the correct diacritics.
I have added this into the body:

```
`$body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body)`
```

And also changed the headers to:

```
`$headers = @{
            "Content-Type"="application/json; charset=utf-8";
            "OData-MaxVersion"="4.0";
            "OData-Version"="4.0";
        };`
```

This is the request:

```
`$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://<URL>/api/MethodInvoker/InvokeServiceMethod' -Method 'POST' -       Headers $headers -Body $body
`
```

I tried to use Postman, several different encodings, changed headers, etc.

Comment: In short: In the absence of `charset` information in the _response_ header, _Windows PowerShell_ defaults to ISO-8859-1 character encoding. _PowerShell (Core) 7.0 - 7.3.x_ default to UTF-8 _for JSON only_, v7.4+ will _generally_ default to UTF-8. If the de-facto encoding differs (e.g, UTF-8) and you have no way of getting the service to include `charset` information to its response, you'll have to _manually_ decode the response using the encoding of choice, based on the response body's _raw bytes_, via `Invoke-WebRequest`.
See the linked duplicates for details.

Answer (score 2):

#### tl;dr

This normally indicates the server is *encoding* the content into a response byte stream in one format (e.g. `utf8`) but the client is *decoding* the byte stream using a different format (e.g. `iso-8859-1`). As a result, the content decoded by the client doesn't match the original content encoded by the server.

This snippet shows the effect in action:

```
$originalContent = "Mężczyzna";

# encode with utf8
$encodedBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($originalContent);

# decode with iso-8859-1
$decodedContent = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString($encodedBytes)

$decodedContent
# MÄÅ¼czyzna
```

Unfortunately it's not 100% guaranteed to be able to reverse the process - mis-decoding some inputs is lossy so you can't *always* recover the original content by reversing the decoding and encoding steps, *but* if you write the response to disk PowerShell will just stream the raw response bytes into a file, and you can read it back using the server's encoding format to recover the original content:

```
$filename = "c:\temp\response.txt";

$response = Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri     "https://<URL>/api/MethodInvoker/InvokeServiceMethod" `
    -Method  "POST" `
    -Headers $headers `
    -Body    $body `
    -OutFile $filename;
#   ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^
#   write the raw byte stream to disk without (mis-)decoding it

$text = Get-Content $filename
```

### More Details

The root problem seems to be caused by different interpretations of what the default encoding should be for some content types - for example:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Some systems (including Windows PowerShell) appear to use an older heuristic that assumes content is encoded using `iso-8859-1` unless a [`charset`](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index#charset) optional parameter is specified on the content type - see [RFC2616: Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-3.7.1)

> When no explicit charset parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes of the "text" type are defined to have a default charset value of "ISO-8859-1" when received via HTTP.

For example if Windows PowerShell receives a response with this header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

it will treat it like:

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=iso-8859-1
```

whereas if the response contains this header:

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

Windows PowerShell will use `utf8` to decode it instead.

This interpretation was superseded in [RFC7321: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#appendix-B) where it says:

> The default charset of ISO-8859-1 for text media types has been removed; the default is now whatever the media type definition says.

and since the spec for [RFC8259: The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1) says:

> JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8 [RFC3629].

that's what some clients do, so for those systems this:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

is treated like

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

and they use `utf8` even if no `charset` is specified.

You *could* fix the original issue by getting the owner of the website / api to add the `charset=utf-8` optional parameter onto the `content-type` header which would improve interoperability with *some* clients, but it's not strictly necessary according to the various specs, and may not be straightforward to get applied if the site is owned by a third party.

And based on the above, the reason the `Content-Type: application/json` response header works in Postman is probably that it uses the newer interpretation of the specs and assumes `utf8` encoding for `application/json`, whereas Windows PowerShell is using the older interpretation of `iso-8859-1` encoding.

For reference, this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/175#issuecomment-619593544) was the key to understanding all of this behaviour.

#### Finally...

...if you want a script to help debug these sorts of issues in future I wrote one a while ago in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67182420/3156906. It takes the original text and the mangled text and tries to work out what pair of mismatched encoding / decoding were used mangle the text. When I ran it with your text it gave me this:

```
original string = 'Mężczyzna'
mangled string  = 'MÄÅ¼czyzna'
    source encoding = 'utf-8'
    target encoding = 'iso-8859-1'
original string = 'Mężczyzna'
mangled string  = 'MÄÅ¼czyzna'
    source encoding = 'utf-8'
    target encoding = 'iso-8859-13'
original string = 'Mężczyzna'
mangled string  = 'MÄÅ¼czyzna'
    source encoding = 'utf-8'
    target encoding = 'iso-8859-9'
```

Comment: The state of things in relation to PowerShell editions / versions: v7+ defaults to UTF-8 for JSON only, v7.4+ will be UTF-8 for all media types.  Since ISO-8859-1 can represent _all_ 8-bit values, re-encoding of mis-decoded strings should work robustly, The first linked duplicate show an alternative based on decoding the _raw byte stream_ directly (come to think of it: not sure about performance implications,, but at least no temporary file is required).

Comment: Saying that it isn't PowerShell's fault may be a bit too generous, at least in the case of JSON: the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) is from 2006 and stipulates UTF-8 as the default, and generally limits support to UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.

Comment: @mklement0 - sure, but the HTTP protocol RFC (/me handwaves away the details:-)) also says the default encoding in lieu of any overrides is “iso-8859-1”, so I’d argue (maybe a bit pedantically, tbf) the HTTP response being sent from the server is technically the root cause as it’s encoding in one format but declaring another (or more likely, not declaring *any*). Powershell is processing the response “correctly” according to the HTTP spec, but the encoded response doesn’t actually represent the original unencoded data.

Comment: But doesn't the use of a specific media type with _its own_ default override the (now obsolete) general ISO-8859-1 HTTP default?

Comment: Granted, the PowerShell cmdlets, as generalists, would have to know all media types to honor specific defaults (clearly, JSON was accommodated explicitly in 7.0), but this will be moot in v7.4+ when we'll live in happy UTF-8-always times.

Comment: Well that’s a good question :-)…

Comment: @mklement0 - I’ve not checked the links, but this seems like they know what they’re talking about… https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/175#issuecomment-619593544. I’ll refine my answer after I’ve finished my kids bedtime…

Comment: Good info, thanks; there's also a dedicated RFC: [RFC 2046](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6657); if I read it correctly, it says: Each media type should define its own behavior, and either _mandate_ a `charset` attribute or _not use it_, which assumes in-band specification (such as an XML document's `encoding` attribute in the XML declaration). If there's "a strong reason" to define a default nonetheless, UTF-8 should be used.

Comment: @mklement0 - my "refining" ended up being a fairly big rewrite...