# ASCII encoding does not work in powershell

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, ascii, text-files

Just can't get ASCII encoding get to work in PowerShell. Tried a bunch of different approaches.

Whatever I try I get an UTF8 encoded file (that is what NPP tells me):

```
$newLine = "Ein Test öäü"
$newLine | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\check.txt"  -Encoding ascii
```

PSVersion = 5.1.14393.5066

Any hint is welcome!

Comment: `öäü` obviously can't be stored in ASCII

Comment: Ascii is not Utf8.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when I do

$newLine = "Test with 7 bit only"
$newLine | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\check.txt"  -Encoding ascii

I get an UTF-8 file instead of an ascii file!!

Comment: I found out when reading the raw bytes:
ANSI: ö --> 246
UTF8: ö --> 195 182
Can I force PowerShell to create ANSI?

Answer (score 3):

ASCII is a **7-bit** character set and doesn't contain any accented character, so obviously storing `öäü` in ASCII doesn't work. If you need UTF-8 then you need to specify encoding as `utf8`

```
$newLine = "Ein Test öäü"
$newLine | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\check.txt" -Encoding utf8
```

If you need another encoding then specify it accordingly. For example to get the ANSI code page use this

```
$newLine = "Ein Test öäü"
$newLine | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\check.txt" -Encoding default
```

`-Encoding default` will save the file in the current ANSI code page and `-Encoding oem` will use the current OEM code page. Just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `-Encoding` and PowerShell will cycle through the list of supported encodings. For encodings not in that list you can trivially deal with them using [System.Text.Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-6.0)

Note that ["ANSI code page" is a misnomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Details) and the actual encoding changes depending on each environment so it won't be reliable. For example if you change the code page manually then it won't work anymore. For a more reliable behavior you need to explicitly specify the encoding (typically Windows-1252 for Western European languages). In older PowerShell use

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines("c:\temp\check.txt", $newLine, [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)
```

and in PowerShell Core you can use

```
$newLine | Out-File -FilePath "check2.txt" -Encoding ([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252))
```

See [How do I change my Powershell script so that it writes out-file in ANSI - Windows-1252 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55265157/995714)

Comment: Nice! I would just add that for PS 5.1 the script file must be saved in UTF-8-with-BOM encoding.

Comment: I need obligatory ASCII, and unfortunately, even when I do 

$newLine = "Test with 7 bit only" 
$newLine | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\check.txt" -Encoding ascii 

I get an UTF-8 file instead of an ascii file!!

Comment: I found out when reading the raw bytes:
ANSI: ö --> 246
UTF8: ö --> 195 182
Can I force PowerShell to create ANSI?

Comment: @StefanGasteiger obviously. You can specify any encoding you want. But note that there's no such thing as "ANSI". `ö` is code point 246 in ISO-8859-1 and Windows 1252 which are the default encodings on Western locales

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
$file    = "c:\temp\check-ansi.txt"
$newLine = "Ein Test öÖäÄüÜ"
   
Remove-Item $file
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $newLine, [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591))
```